# FileHelpers Master/Detail Records with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, filehelpers

I'm having problems getting the master detail records to work with generics. My code is as follows

```
// Setup file engine with Master/Detail types
MasterDetailEngine<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine> engine = new MasterDetailEngine<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine>(CommonSelector.MasterIfBegins, "H");

// Init the Master/Detail
MasterDetails<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine> poRecs = new MasterDetails<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine>();

// Setup list for detail lines & populate with test data
List<PurchaseOrderLine> poLines = new List<PurchaseOrderLine>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    poLines.Add(new PurchaseOrderLine() { LineMarker = "L", LineNumber = i, ItemCode = "TestCode", Price = 12.34M, Quantity = i * 2, UOM = "EA" });
}

// Attach records to Master/Detail
poRecs.Master = new PurchaseOrderHeader() { LineMarker = "H", PayloadID = "3223232@ariba.acme.com", CustomerPO = "DO1234", ShipToAddressCode = "ShipToAddressCode", BillToAddressCode = "BillToAddressCode" };
poRecs.Details = poLines.ToArray();

// Write file
engine.WriteFile("SampleFile.txt", poRecs);
```

I get the following compilation error:

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `FileHelpers.MasterDetail.MasterDetailEngine<ImportExport.PurchaseOrderHeader,ImportExport.PurchaseOrderLine>.WriteFile(string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FileHelpers.MasterDetail.MasterDetails<ImportExport.PurchaseOrderHeader,ImportExport.PurchaseOrderLine>>)`
>
> has some invalid arguments.

I've tried casting `poRecs` to `IEnumerable` but that still doesn't work right.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the call to `WriteFile` expects an `IEnumerable<MasterDetails<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine>>`, while you're just passing in a `MasterDetails<PurchaseOrderHeader, PurchaseOrderLine>`.

Of course you can't cast a `MasterDetails` to an `IEnumerable` because those aren't convertible. What you need to do is wrap `poRecs` with an `IEnumerable`. Try the following:

```
engine.WriteFile("SampleFile.txt", new[] { poRecs });
```